# Returning ‘Nothing’ if an indexed list traversal doesn’t match

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I’m new to `lens` and trying to use it to compose many small modifications to a nested structure, which may fail and possibly return additional results:

```
element -> Maybe element
element -> Maybe (result, element)
```

How do I modify an inner structure *by index*, also returning `Nothing` if the index isn’t present? If I use `traverseOf`+`ix`:

```
type Thing = (String, [Int])

exampleThing :: Thing
exampleThing = ("example", [0, 1])

predMaybe :: Int -> Maybe Int
predMaybe x
  | x == 0 = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just (pred x)

decrementThingAt :: Int -> Thing -> Maybe Thing
decrementThingAt i = traverseOf (_2 . ix i) predMaybe
```

```
> decrementThingAt 1 exampleThing
Just ("example",[0,0])

> decrementThingAt 0 exampleThing
Nothing
```

Then if the index isn’t present, this silently returns the structure unmodified:

```
> decrementThingAt 2 exampleThing
Just ("example",[0,1])
```

Whereas I want to return `Nothing` here as well. I’d like to do it “inside” the lens composition if possible. I know I can use `preview` / `^?` “outside” to get a `Maybe` according to whether an optic matched any targets:

```
> preview (_2 . ix 1) exampleThing
Just 1

> preview (_2 . ix 2) exampleThing
Nothing
```

But I expected to be able to write something like `traverseOf (_2 . ix i . previewed) predMaybe`. I see some awkward ways to do it “outside”, like with `foldMapOf`:

```
decrementThingAt i = getFirst . foldMapOf (_2 . ix i) (First . predMaybe)
```

But is there a way to keep everything in the same pipeline, so that I’m not repeatedly/explicitly disassembling & reassembling the structure?

I also don’t quite see how to combine this with returning additional results. At the moment I’m using `StateT` and `zoom` like this:

```
import Control.Lens (_1, zoom)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State (StateT, runStateT)
import Data.List (uncons)

-- NB: uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])

pop :: Thing -> Maybe (Char, Thing)
pop = runStateT $ zoom _1 $ StateT uncons
```

```
> pop exampleThing
Just ('e',("xample",[0,1]))

> pop ("", [0, 1])
Nothing
```

But I still don’t know how to make that work with missing indices, for example, using `type ThingMaybe = (Maybe String, [Int])` and failing if that `Maybe` is `Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't possible.  To see why, let's look at your `decrementThingAt` example.  Let's say you came up with some traversal that did what you want.  That is, you could write

```hs
decrementThingAt :: Int -> Thing -> Maybe Thing
decrementThingAt i = traverseOf myTrav predMaybe
```

such that

```hs
> decrementThingAt 1 exampleThing
Just ("example",[0,0])

> decrementThingAt 2 exampleThing
Nothing
```

Now, let's explore the function:

```hs
unknown :: Int -> Thing -> Thing
unknown i = myTrav %~ id
```

With any normal traversal, `unknown n t == t` for all (type-correct) choices of `n` and `t`, but with `myTrav`, that's not clear anymore.  If you call `unknown 2 exampleThing`, presumably you want it to return ... `Nothing`?  That doesn't even make sense at the type level.

Looking at it another way, you can't construct a traversal `myTrav` for the same reason that no many how many times you run

```hs
> traverse predMaybe []
Just []
```

you'll never get `Nothing`.  The traversal `ix` essentially filters out the elements of the list that you're calling `predMaybe` on, and when you `ix` on an index that isn't present, it's like you filtered out all elements.  There ends up being no call to `predMaybe`, so there's no way to return `Nothing`.

As you correctly identified, the right way to do what you're looking for is "outside" the traversal.  This makes sense: it's the same level that you're declaring the use of `predMaybe`, which, after all, is where the `Maybe` applicative is coming into play.  For example, your use of `First` and `foldMapOf` works because `First` is a monoid with the property that `mempty ≈ Nothing`, just as you want.

---

When it comes to returning additional results, I like using the `(a,)` functor:

```hs
import Data.Functor.Compose

pop :: Thing -> Maybe (Char, Thing)
pop = getCompose . _1 (Compose . uncons)

-- Or if you prefer using all the lens operators:
-- pop t = getCompose $ t & _1 %%~ (Compose . uncons)
```

In this case, it's made a little extra complicated by the need to use `Compose`, but it still ends up doing what I want.

As for returning `Nothing` when indices are missing, you're going to run into the same problem I described above.

---

#### Some Options

For what it's worth, I believe the simplest way to achieve the goal you're looking for is *not* to do it at the "inside" level but to do it at the outside level, and there's no reason this will end up "repeatedly/explicitly disassembling & reassembling the structure".  Consider something like this:

```hs
maybeToAny :: Maybe a -> Compose Maybe ((,) Any) a
maybeToAny = Compose . fmap (Any True,)

getIfAny :: Compose Maybe ((,) Any) a -> Maybe a
getIfAny (Compose Nothing) = Nothing
getIfAny (Compose (Just (Any False, _))) = Nothing
getIfAny (Compose (Just (Any True, a))) = Just a

decrementThingAt :: Int -> Thing -> Maybe Thing
decrementThingAt i = getIfAny . traverseOf (_2 . ix i) (maybeToAny . predMaybe)
```

The idea here is we use the `Any` value to check if `maybeToAny . predMaybe` was ever called.  If it was, then the `Any` value will be `True`, and we can produce the result value, and otherwise, our traversal must have missed, so we return `Nothing`.

---

If you really want to do this "inside" the optic, We can also make a pseudo-traversal that follows the same principle:

```hs
ixj :: Ixed m => Index m -> Traversal' (Maybe m) (IxValue m)
ixj i _ Nothing = pure Nothing
ixj i afb (Just s) =
  let t' = getCompose $ s & ix i %%~ Compose . fmap (Any True,) . afb
      go (Any True, t)  = Just t
      go (Any False, _) = Nothing
  in go <$> t'
```

Note that we need the `s` type to be `Maybe m` instead of just `m` so that we can fail.  Unfortunately, this is not a true traversal because it doesn't obey the traversal laws (this whole idea of failing is contrary to how optics work).  I still managed to come up with something, but it's a little ugly:

```hs
finside :: Applicative f => ALens s t a b -> Lens (f s) (f t) (f a) (f b)
finside (cloneLens -> l) = lens (fmap $ getConst . l Const) (liftA2 $ flip (l .~))

decrementThingAt :: Int -> Thing -> Maybe Thing
decrementThingAt i = join . traverseOf (finside _2 . ixj i) predMaybe . Just
```

(I'm not sure if `finside` or something similar already exists in the lens library.  I'm also not sure if what it produces will always obey the lens laws.)

Comment: Thanks, that’s a bit clearer. I am a bit surprised—“traverse the value in a map, requiring the key be present, without an extra `preview` to check” seems like it would be a common enough use case. To check my understanding—are you interpreting `traverseOf` as a requirement here? To be clear, I don’t mind using a different “driver” function, as long as the optic/combinator fits into a pipeline somehow. (Say, like `required (field . at i) . anotherField . …` where the hypothetical `required` serves the role of my equally hypothetical `previewed` but maybe has more context available.)

Comment: I'm a little confused.  When you said you didn't want to use `foldMapOf`, it sounded like you _did_ think of `traverseOf` as a requirement.  If it's not, what's wrong with using your `foldMapOf` trick?  As for your hypothetical `required` or `previewed` optics, do you have a proposed type for them?  I guess what I was trying to get it in my answer is that I don't know what it means for something to be "required" in a traversal.  A traversal needs an arbitrary Applicative, but you seem to want to restrict that Applicative to be `Maybe`.

Comment: I’m sorry, unfortunately I don’t know what I don’t know here. I saw things like `failover` (which uses `Alternative`), `has`/`hasn't` for folds, and `isn't` for prisms, and I thought there would be such a thing for indices. As for a type, my latest attempt is this: `rix :: Ixed a => Index a -> LensLike' Maybe a (IxValue a); rix i f x = preview (ix i) x *> traverseOf (ix i) f x`. With this, `traverseOf (_2 . rix i) predMaybe` _seems_ to work as expected, it just also seems odd to redundantly `preview` when I’m going to traverse anyway. Also, not sure this is lawful.

Comment: Ahh!  So, `rix` may suit your needs, but it's not technically a lens or a traversal because you've fixed the type of `f` to `Maybe`.  It will work in some combinators (e.g., `traverseOf`), but not all (e.g., `toListOf`), and even when it works, it has limitations (`\i -> traverseOf (_2 . rix i) id` doesn't type-check).

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a couple of alternative ways to do what you're trying to do.  Maybe they'll be helpful or spark a good idea for you!

Comment: Yes, there are combinators like `failover` and `has`/`hasn't`, but as combinators, those are "outside" rather than "inside" (that is, they take optics as arguments and are not optics themselves) — that's why they can fail. (EDIT: When I wrote `\i -> traverseOf (_2 . rix i) id` in the above comment, I meant `\i -> traverseOf (_2 . rix i) Identity`)

Comment: The pair functor feels a bit heavy for the job. Is it possible to trim down a bit?

Comment: What's lighter than the pair functor?  Like I said in my answer, this whole thing is analogous to writing `traverse myPred lst` and _not_ wanting `Just []` when `lst = []`.  The simplest modification I see is to pair the result with a simple monoid like `Any` and guard the result on that value.

Comment: You're probably right. I'm going to need to think about it a bit more.

Comment: Isn't this using the `Applicative` instance of `(,) Any`? If so, that's not wonderful, because `liftA2` is lazy in the first component. So we'll build a big thunk chain there through the traversal. Any way you try to order it will potentially make the traversal stricter than desired. *sigh*